# Minimum distance of a symmetric matrix to diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, matrix-analysis

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an arbitrary $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix and $n\geq 2$. Let $\| \cdot \|$ denote the operator $2$-norm or equivalently the maximum absolute value of eigenvalues for symmetric matrices. Define

$$d(A) := \min_{D \text{ is diagonal}} \|A-D\|,$$

as the minimum distance of $A$ from diagonal matrices. What is the best constant $C$  that we can put in the following inequality?

$$d(A) \leq C \max_{i \neq j} |a_{ij}|.$$

The constant $C=n-1$ obviously works, by considering the distance of $A$ from its own diagonal, but it can be shown that it's not the smallest constant for $n>2$.

Comment: "But it can be shown that it's not the smallest constant." Please show us a smaller (the smallest) constant you know with proof.

Comment: @Stone I don't know a smaller constant, but there is a smallest constant (compactness argument) and I know that there is no matrix such that $d(A)/\max(|a_{ij}|)=n-1$. My proof for this fact is rather long and may be irrelevant to finding the best $C$, so I didn't write it here.

Comment: I don't think there's a smaller constant for $n=1, 2$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, my argument also works for $n>2$. I edited this remark in the question.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone To set up the "triviality level", the obvious lower bound is $n/2$ (consider all ones outside the diagonal) and the obvious upper bound is $\sqrt{\frac{n(n-1)}2}$ (take the distance from the off-diagonal part to multiples of identity and take into account that the sum of the squares of the eigenvalues is $\le n(n-1)\max|a_{ij}|^2$). So, roughly speaking, we are between $\frac n2$ and $\frac n{\sqrt 2}$ and I do not know which bound is closer to the truth...

Comment: @MTyson - Does your argument suggest that the closest diagonal matrix to A is the diagonal of A? If so, that's not true (when $n \geq 3$). For what it's worth, we solved the problem of finding the closest matrix D when A has rank 1 in [arXiv:1601.06269](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06269), but the formula is quite nasty (see Theorem 1).

Comment: @NathanielJohnston I see, thanks! I was thinking of the Schatten $2$-norm rather than the operator $2$-norm.

Comment: @fedja I think you should also consider the absolute value of diagonal entries in the upper bound estimate, so I can't see that "the sum of the squares of the eigenvalues $\leq n(n-1)\max_{i\neq j} |a_{ij}|^2$" ...

Comment: Dear Mostafa,  I think WLOG we could consider diagonal entries of $ A $ equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.14958) it is shown that $C=\frac{n}{2}$ is the best constant for the above problem. Also the similar problem for Hermitian matrices is also investigated and it is shown that for this more larger set of matrices, the best constant $C$, is equal to $\cot(\frac{\pi}{2n})$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Please see the edited version of the question.