# Does this matrix norm inequality have interesting application in other areas of mathematics?

Tags: matrix-analysis, quantum-mechanics, algebraic-combinatorics, operator-norms, coherence

In my new [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.14958), one of the main theorems gives an upper bound for the spectral distance of a general real symmetric matrix to diagonal matrices:

> **Theorem 3.** ‎Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be a real symmetric matrix of order $n>1$‎. ‎Then‎
> ‎$$\min_{D\in \mathcal{D}_n} \Vert{A-D}\Vert_{\infty} \;\leq\; \frac{n}{2}\max_{i\neq j} |a_{ij}|,$$
> ‎and the bound is sharp for all $n>1$‎.

($\mathcal{D}_n$ stands for the space of diagonal matrices of order $n$ and $\Vert A\Vert_\infty$ denotes the "spectral" norm of the matrix $A$, which is the maximum singular value.)

It seems to me that this is a new and nontrivial bound for the distance to the nearest diagonal matrix, and should have some interesting applications or consequences in other areas of mathematics, specially algebraic combinatorics or quantum coherence. For the second, I also read a bunch of papers on coherence measure, without obtaining any remarkable relation between the above theorem and works there.

Does anyone have ideas or suggestions in this respect?

Comment: Statistics, and in particular diagonal approximations to covariance matrices. One might try to bound how much worse is a model based on the best diagonal matrix is than the full matrix model. But that's only if you consider statistics to be an area of mathematics ;).

Comment: @Oxonon Which norms are used to measure the distance of covariance matrices?

Comment: The operator norm, since we would usually care about worst-case performance.

Comment: @Oxonon Nice! So do you think the mentioned theorem above, may have some application in statistics? As I'm not an expert in this subject, could you please give some references?

Comment: The distance between a matrix and the closest diagonal matrix (usually measured in the trace norm in this context) comes up naturally in quantum information theory when trying to quantify "how coherent" a quantum state is. See [arXiv:1551.01854](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01854), for example.

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/349044/11260

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, I'm the author. I didnt find this necessary to mention, but I made an edit to the question to respond your request

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The aim of this question is merely to find some connections and applications for this work for making it applicable for publishing in a high rank journal.

Comment: Thanks @Mostafa !

Comment: @Mostafa Just to clarify, let me note that it is always necessary to mention that you are the author of a paper you mention in your messages, by the rules in https://mathoverflow.net/help/promotion . Thanks for complying!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni : I do not see there a rule saying that it is always necessary to mention that "you" are the author of a paper "you" mention in your message. I do see "you must disclose your affiliation" there, and frankly I do not understand the purpose of disclosing the affiliation by the author of the paper.

Comment: @IosifPinelis In my reading, "disclose your affiliation" means "disclose that you are the author", i.e., your affiliation *with the paper*. "Affiliation" here is used as a synonym of "association", and it doesn't mean "your university/employer". If you disagree, we can ask for a confirmation on meta.mo that this is the case. I hope the purpose is clearer with this reading.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni : I have never seen elsewhere that one can be affiliated with a thing (such as a paper), rather than with a group/organization of people; see e.g. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/affiliation

Comment: @FedericoPoloni --- I asked on https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5778/11260 (this discussion is probably better suited for Meta than here)